# Cant add tabs to tabhost Android (API 17+)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I build my first app and all works fine till i would add a menu (Navigation drawer) I have added the menu and now i need to use fragments and nested fragments for my content instead of activities with fragments.

What i try to build is:
[image]

There are 2 tabs for switching between list and maps view.
Under it i need 3 buttons for selecting the shown content for example all alerts, only level 1 alerts or only level 2 alerts.

Main activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_menu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment_main layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="aaeu.app.presentationlayer.MainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp">
        <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    </FrameLayout>
                </TabWidget>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/all_alerts"
            android:id="@+id/btn_all_alerts"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/amber_alerts"
            android:id="@+id/btn_ambert_alerts"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/endangered_missings"
            android:id="@+id/btn_missings"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Main fragment code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import aaeu.app.R;


public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private TabHost mTabHost;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mTabHost = (TabHost)v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
                AlertOverviewMapsFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
                AlertOverviewListFragment.class, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

List fragment layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentationlayer.AlertOverviewListFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lv_alert_overview"></ListView>    
</FrameLayout>
```

List fragment code:

```
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import aaeu.app.R;
import aaeu.app.businesslayer.AppManager;
import aaeu.app.datalayer.Alert;
import aaeu.app.datalayer.e_Alerts;
import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnItemClick;

public class AlertOverviewListFragment extends Fragment implements e_Alerts {

    @Bind(R.id.lv_alert_overview) ListView lv_alert_overview;
    List<Alert> alerts = new ArrayList<Alert>();
    AppManager manager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Load alerts when fragment starts
        manager = new AppManager();
        final WeakReference<e_Alerts> wr = new WeakReference<e_Alerts>(this);
        this.alerts = manager.getAlerts(wr, this.getContext());
    }

    // Updates the list after asynctask is ready
    @Override
    public void UpdateAlerts(List<Alert> alerts)
    {
        //Fill array adapter with alerts from datalayer and set adapter for the listview
        this.alerts = alerts;
        updateList();
    }
```

I constanly get the error :
*Error:(39, 17) error: method addTab in class TabHost cannot be applied to given types;
required: TabHost.TabSpec
found: TabHost.TabSpec,Class,
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length*

I know this is not the first topic/question about this an i read a lot of the questions. I got this solution from one of them but i cant get it working.

I think this has something to do with `import android.app.Fragment;` and `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` but i'am not sure about that. I only need support for API17 and newer so i dont need the support library.
Can someone explain me what i doing wrong? I prefer a solution where i don't need to change my whole app or edit all classes/fragments or something.

**----------------UPDATE----------------**

When is use:

```
        // Tab for Listview
        TabHost.TabSpec listspec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Listview");
// setting Title for the Tab
        listspec.setIndicator("Listview");
        Intent listIntent = new Intent(getContext(), AlertOverviewListFragment.class);
        listspec.setContent(listIntent);

   mTabHost.addTab(listspec);
```

instead of:

```
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
            AlertOverviewListFragment.class, null);
```

i got the error

`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{aaeu.app/aaeu.app.presentationlayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?`

Comment: **1)** TabHost is obsolete, use [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). If you're following a tutorial older than, let's say two years, just don't. **2)** Just because you target API >= 14 and can use native fragments doesn't mean you shouldn't use support-v4 or appcompat-v7 library. I love support-v4. It's platform independent.